# Pytube caption generating issue

Tags: python, pytube

I have YouTube link. I need to extract captions from the video. My code is -

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube('https://youtu.be/.....')
caption =yt.captions.get_by_language_code('en')
print(caption.generate_srt_captions())
 
Output = > 00:00:01 --> 00:00:02
This is caption ex..
00:00:03--> 00:00:04
This is second line
```

Need that type output

This is caption This is second line

Comment: What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

output is string, so u can use .split('\n'). I made simple for loop to loop through every line and save only time and caption to dictionary. It isn't best solution but it works.

```
from pytube import YouTube


caption_list = []
index = 0
yt = YouTube('https://youtu.be/.....')
caption = yt.captions.get_by_language_code('en')
for line in str(caption.generate_srt_captions()).split('\n'):
    if index == 0:
        caption_list.append({})
    if index in (1, 2):
        caption_list[len(caption_list)-1][('time', 'caption')[index-1]] = line
    index += 1
    if line == '':
        index = 0
for dic in caption_list:
    print('{} : {}'.format(dic['time'], dic['caption']))
```